# how to sql query 2 tables and group by?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum

i have 2 tables: activities and users.
users has columns: name, active
activities: name, type, time, user_id.

for example i have these tables:

```
users
-----
id | name | active
1  | marc | true
2  | john | true
3  | mary | true
4  | nico | true

activities
-----
id | name | type | time | user_id
1  | morn | walk | 90   | 2
2  | morn | walk | 22   | 2
3  | morn | run  | 12   | 2
4  | sat  | walk | 22   | 1
5  | morn | run  | 13   | 1
6  | mond | walk | 22   | 3
7  | morn | walk | 22   | 2
8  | even | run  | 42   | 1
9  | morn | walk | 22   | 3
10 | morn | walk | 62   | 1
11 | morn | run  | 22   | 3
```

now i would like to get table that would sum time spent on each type of activity and would group it by user name. so:

```
result
------
user name | type | time
marc      | walk | 84
marc      | run  | 55
john      | walk | 134
john      | run  | 12
mary      | walk | 44
mary      | run  | 2
nico      | walk | 0
nico      | run  | 0
```

how should i write this query to get this result?

thanks in advance
gerard

Comment: Looks like a great homework assignment, why don't you try posting your attempt to solve this problem? We're here to help, not work

Comment: Actually, you want to group it by user name and activity.  This is fundamental sql.  Since you don't know how to do it, you might consider learning the basics before trying to do things.  To that end, I've heard good things about the book, Teach Yourself SQL in 10 Minutes.

Comment: you are right, i tried already to write correct sql query, but i got confused, so i decided to ask a question here. looking for answers i see that there's simple solution. next time i will try to try harder. thanks for your opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `coalesce` to get 0 for empty activities and `distinct` to get all type of possible activities

```
select
   u.name, c.type,
   coalesce(sum(a.time), 0) as time
from (select distinct type from activities) as c
   cross join users as u
   left outer join activities as a on a.user_id = u.id and a.type = c.type
group by u.name, c.type
order by u.name, c.type
```

[**<kbd>sql fiddle demo</kbd>**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/4886f/44)

Answer (score 1):

```
Select u.name, a.type, SUM(a.time) FROM 
activities a
LEFT JOIN users u
ON a.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.name, a.type
```

**[FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/4886f/3)**

Use this to get zero count as well

```
SELECT c.name,c.type,aa.time FROM
(Select u.id,u.name, b.type  FROM 
users u
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT type FROM activities) b) c
LEFT JOIN (SELECT a.user_id, a.type, SUM(a.time) as time FROM
activities a 
GROUP BY a.user_id, a.type) aa ON
aa.user_id = c.id and c.type = aa.type
```

**[Fiddle2](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/4886f/37)**

Comment: thanks, it works.i just miss how to diplay users with 0 minute activity

Comment: @gerpaick it could be made much cleaner. I think query should be as readable as possible, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

this might work :

```
select users.name,activities.type,sum(activities.time)
from users left join activities on users.id = activities.user_id
where users.active group by users.name,activities.type
```